# React table - Resizable columns with column width in percentage

Tags: react-table

I'm trying to implement table in react that satisfies below requirement:

1. Column is resizable
2. Table width is not fixed, just full fill the table's container
3. Column width can be in pixcel or percentage
4. If columns width is not set, they will occupy the rest of horizontal space of table

I see some suggestions to use react-table. Here is one example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/column-resizing

But this library seems to be:

- Column width must be set for every column (requirement #2, #4 not satisfied)
- Not supporting column width in percentage (requirement #3 not satisfied)

could anyone help suggest me how I can handle with react-table to adapt needed requirements? 
If it's impossible with react-table, do you know any other library or any other approach I can try ?
Thankyou all!